# ReactiveSearch (Web): Pagination gets reset once returning to same page

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I am working on `ReactiveSearch`, in which I am using `URLParams` to maintain search selections of user through route changes.

When on any page other than first, after refreshing browser, user gets on that page,
but once user change the page and visit same page again, by click on pagination, it redirects user to first page rather than that page.

On Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/appbaseio/reactivesearch/tree/next/packages/web/examples/ReactiveList?from-embed), if you refresh page after navigating to `Page 3`, and do navigation by going to `Page 2` and again to `Page 3`, you will be redirected to `Page 1`.

Is there any work around I can fix this till issue gets fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They have updated their repo now and above issue is resolved.